# Ipworks data loss

Tags: c#, sockets, ipworks

I use ipworks ipport component. when datain event has been fired,i put the data in a queue and then process it in a different thread.  Data is coming too fast, and I reliezed that incoming data is missing. How can i resolve this?

Comment: Either increase the size of your buffer, process the data faster, or both.

Comment: Have you considered modifying the thread's priority? I have an application where the reading thread have a maximum priority while the process thread is in normal priority, and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the data loss is happening exactly but the DataIn event will provide all of the incoming data, what happens after that would be up to you.

I work for nsoftware and if you'd like to e-mail our support team (support@nsoftware.com) with your code and any other details we'll be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: My guess would be that he's still processing previous events when the next events fire.  That could result in data loss (possibly from his code, even if your code handles it).  The solution, as I mentioned in comments, is to either buffer the data (more) or process it faster (or both).